# Charge: Update subscription card details

Tags: plugins, plugin-charge, stripe

I am attempting to create a form where the user can update their subscription card details (with Stripe Elements).

From looking at the Charge plugin's source code, I believe the endpoint I need is `charge/updateSubscription`.

As with checkout I am creating an opts hidden input in my twig template like so:

```
{{
  craft.charge.setPaymentOptions({
    planAmount: currentSubscription.planAmount,
    planInterval: currentSubscription.planInterval,
    planIntervalCount: currentSubscription.planIntervalCount
  })
}}
```

And then making a POST request with Javascript to the endpoint:

```
getStripeToken(cardToken => {
  post({
    params: {
      action: 'charge/updateSubscription',
      opts,
      cardToken,
      subscriptionId
    },
    then: response => console.log(response)
    url: '/'
  })
})
```

Quite simply, this doesn't work. I receive a `{success: true}` response, but the Stripe card has not been updated.

Does anybody what I'm doing wrong, or even if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I worked out the card is related to a customer, not a subscription.

I couldn't see any public endpoint to update a customer's card, so I added this method in `charge/controllers/ChargeController.php` (not ideal to update the plugin directly I know):

```
public function actionUpdateCard()
{
  $this->requirePostRequest();
  $customer = craft()->charge_customer->find();
  $cardToken = craft()->request->getRequiredPost('cardToken');

  if ($customer->addCard($cardToken)) {
    $this->returnJson(['success' => true]);
  } else {
    $this->returnJson(['success' => false]);
  }
}
```

and then can make requests to the `charge/updateCard` endpoint:

```
getStripeToken(cardToken => {
  post({
    params: {
      action: 'charge/updateCard',
      cardToken
    },
    then: ({ success }) => console.log(`Card updated: ${success}`)
    url: '/'
  })
})
```